# how to insert a value to sql database by summing last row value and the inserting value

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

my table like this

```
id  debt   balance
1   1000   
2   500    
3   600
```

i want table like this when i insert new debt value

```
id  debt   balance
1   1000   1000
2   500    1500
3   600    2100
```

eg when i add debt value 1000 need to update balance as sum of the value

```
id  debt   balance
1   1000   1000
2   500    1500
3   600    2100
4   1000   3100
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. This is not a coding service website. Show us, what you have done so far in a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and you'll get help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT balance from table order by desc limit 1
```

after fetching last balance add it to the current dept value

```
$balance = $row['balance'];
```

```
$dept = $_POST['dept'];
$new_val = $dept+$balance;
```

add this new_val to the new balance field

```
INSERT INTO table (debt, balance) VALUES ('$dept', '$new_val');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try below

```
update tablename
set balance=debt+(select balance from tablename order by id desc limit 1)
```